# Find 2 Blank Cells adjacent to each other in a range

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to write some code to look for 2 cells that are both blank and adjacent to each other in Excel and having no luck.

so in a table like this -

```
|Title|Col 1|Col 2|Col 3|Col 4|Col 5|Col 6|
|Row 1|Data |Data |     |     |     |     |
|Row 2|Data |     |Data |     |     |     |
```

I want the code to find both Cells in Col 4 - but at best I can get it to find the first blank in Col 3 Row 1 or Col 2 Row 2.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Can you post some more detail about the business requirement? What is the purpose of this? What are you trying to achieve? Do you need VBA? Are you after a formula? Please help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through all cells in the range and test whether any surrounding cell is blank using IsEmpty().
But I admit this would be kinda slow.